# Is it a good practice to query an object with realm outside transaction?

Tags: android, realm

I was wondering.. is it a good practice to query some object outside a realm transaction? I mean, I don't want to modify that object, I just want to get the object and see its data.

Is this code well done?

```
Articulo mArticulo = realm.where(Articulo.class).and().equalTo("IDArticulo", 2).findFirst();
```

Or is it mandatory to do it like this?

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
        Articulo mArticulo = realm.where(Articulo.class).and().equalTo("IDArticulo", 2).findFirst();
    }
});
```

And what happens if I want to use that item outside the transaction? Because I cannot have access to it from outside that transaction. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transactions are for modifying data, aka "write transaction".

You don't need them to start reading data.

Beginning a write transaction blocks the thread if there is an open write transaction on any other thread/process. But it bumps the version to latest when you start, which can sometimes be handy on background threads.

One thing to note is that when you do need to modify data in a RealmResults, you should either use an iterator, enhanced for loop, or only use int index backwards, or use int index on a snapshot collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I just want to let you know that I'm using your post https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149 as a reference since I started to use Realm. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please explain the last part of your answer? I understand the iterator part, but I don't totally understand what you mean with backwards index neither the snapshot collection.

Comment: If you use `realmResults.get(i)` inside a write transaction and you're changing the data in such a way that the query results change, then those changes are immediate inside transactions, so you need to either call `.createSnapshot()` and iterate on that, or iterate in reverse.

Comment: Good to know, as I'm still a rookie working with Realm, I haven't still had the chance to modify data inside an iteration, but now I'm already advised. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use that query outside `executeTransaction()` method as long as you provide right instance of `Realm`

[For more info, check this out](https://www.realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, when I saw that doc, I was thinking that they omitted the transaction because it was mandatory everywhere, but then I checked and it worked without any problem, so that's why I post my question here.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use transactions when you are changing the Realm objects, such as inserting/deleting/updating them.

To simply get them and use them, without modifying them, you should do it as shown in your first example. That's good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was thinking, but as I didn't find anywhere saying that explicitly, I doubted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to close realm instance manually,

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(){
   Articulo mArticulo = realm.where(Articulo.class).and().equalTo("IDArticulo", 2).findFirst();    
}
```

Here, `mArcticulo` is managed object. Try to avoid dealing with managed objects. 
you can copy managed object to unmaged object,

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(){
   Articulo mArticulo = realm.where(Articulo.class).and().equalTo("IDArticulo", 2).findFirst();    
   if(mArticulo != null)
      mArticulo = realm.copyFromRealm(mArticulo); //better approach

}
```

- Try-with-resources automatically closes the realm instance.

You don't need to use `executeTransaction` for reading purpose. It is required only for writing/modifying objects in Realm.